# ObservableCollection<T> does not update ListView when an Item is added

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I use the following ViewModel in my test project. I've tried to follow MVVM pattern. I need instant update feature in the view.

```
public class StudentListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _lastName;
        private int _age;
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _studentList;
        public string Name 
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                InsertCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        { 
            get => _lastName;
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
                InsertCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get => _age;
            set
            {
                _age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
                InsertCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
        public RelayCommand InsertCommand { get; }

        public StudentListViewModel()
        {
            InsertCommand = new RelayCommand((s) => InsertStudent(),
            () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) && Age > 0);
            using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
            {
                studentList = new ObservableCollection<Student>(context.Students);
            };
        }
        public void InsertStudent()
        {
                Student st = new Student()
                {
                    Name = Name,
                    LastName = LastName,
                    Age = Age
                };
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                context.Add(st);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Student> studentList
        {
            get 
            {
                return _studentList;
            }
            set
            {
                _studentList = value;
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I add an entry to the database, it does not update the `ListView` and the change is only seen when I rerun the app. The second problem is that property is changed when I leave the cursor focus away from the selected textbox. Is it possible to change property as you fill the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not need to reload entire collection as shown in the other answer. add single item into the current collection:

```
public void InsertStudent()
{
    var st = new Student()
    {
        Name = Name,
        LastName = LastName,
        Age = Age
    };
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        context.Add(st);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    studentList.Add(st);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing OnPropertyChanged in studentList:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Student> studentList
        {
            get 
            {
                return _studentList;
            }
            set
            {
                _studentList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(“studentList”);
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

You need to load the list again when insert a data:

```cs
public void InsertStudent()
        {
                Student st = new Student()
                {
                    Name = Name,
                    LastName = LastName,
                    Age = Age
                };
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                context.Add(st);
                context.SaveChanges();
                studentList = new ObservableCollection<Student>(context.Students);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Be aware that ObservableCollection is not necessary in this scenario.

Comment: @Clemens, why not? reloading full dbset is an overkill compared to adding single item to ObservableCollection

Comment: @ASh sure, but that is not what they are doing here.